# Application crashes because of adapter

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a problem with displaying facebook friend list data in Listview since last week and I cannot figure it out. I tried many ways to do this but unfortunately it didn't succeeded. Friend list is displaying in logcat but when I want to display it in ListView and the application crashes. Null pointer exception error and some other run-time error occurs

Help me with this issue please
I only want to display friends information  in ListView from for loop
    below is my code

```
   public class About extends  Activity {
public ArrayList<String> values;

    ListView listViewPhoneBook;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.phone_book);
        values = new ArrayList<String>();
        getfriends();
        // Log.d("All Data",values.toString());
        ListView listViewPhoneBook=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listPhoneBook);

          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.each_contact, values);
          listViewPhoneBook.setAdapter(adapter);
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}

public void getfriends(){
Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync( (Session)MainActivity.fbSession , new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {


    @Override
        public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response)  {
            for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
                values.add(users.get(i).getName());
            }
            Log.d("All Data1",values.toString());
        }
    });
}
}
```

Logcat

```
   03-20 14:18:28.156: E/ArrayAdapter(21885): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2088)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1249)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1160)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1374)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1022)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:555)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:815)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2108)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1147)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2642)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4666)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
03-20 14:18:28.169: E/AndroidRuntime(21885):    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Can you show us your logcat?

Comment: @Saad welcome to stackoverflow, you should also post your error log so that we can understand the problem and help you.

Comment: I edited my question and logcat is pasted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put

```
values = new ArrayList<String>();
getfriends();
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
    values.add(users.get(i).getName());
    Log.d("FRIENDSNAME",  users.get(i).getName());
}
```

EDIT: final code

Use this code

```
public class About extends  Activity {

/*private String[] values;*/
public ArrayList<String> values;
    //private ActivityList listAdapter;

    ListView listViewPhoneBook;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.phone_book);
        values = new ArrayList<String>();
        listViewPhoneBook=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listPhoneBook);
        getfriends();
        // Log.d("All Data",values.toString());

}


public void updateList()
{
          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.each_contact, values);
          listViewPhoneBook.setAdapter(adapter);
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void getfriends()
{
Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync( (Session)MainActivity.fbSession , new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {


    @Override
        public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response)  {
        /*values = new String[users.size()];*/

            for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
               // values[i] = users.get(i).getName();
                values.add(users.get(i).getName());
               /* Log.d("FRIENDSNAME",  users.get(i).getName());*/

            }
            Log.d("All Data1",values.toString());
            updateList();
        }
    });
}
```